# Connecting to SQLServer with VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem when I'm trying to connect to SQL server, my try-catch block gets an error :

```
Incorrect syntax near '='
```

this is my whole code

```vb
Try

    ' Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;


    myConn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=test;" & _
            "Data Source=SWAT\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;")



    'Create a Command object.
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name " & _
            "FROM clients " & _
            "WHERE idClient = 1"



    'Open the connection.
    myConn.Open()

    '  myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    Using myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
        While myReader.Read
            strServer = myReader.Item("name")
        End While
    End Using



    'Display results.
    MsgBox(strServer)

    'Close the reader and the database connection.
    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)


End Try
```

I've done some debugging but I still don't understand where I'm doing wrong.
[image]

I've tested my connection with Server explorer and it works.
[image]

I really need some help here, I've connected previously to a database in easyPHPSql  without any problems and I've been using almost the same code except the part where I specify the connection  parameters.

I've readed this article and applied most of the code from here : 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308656#top
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've used this as a guide :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308656#top

Comment: one of your problems is, that you don't have space or line break between `where` and the table name `clients`. Parser can't parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a space before the WHERE (or after the table name)

```
  myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name " & _
                      "FROM clients " & _
                      "WHERE idClient = 1"
```

However, there is another error in the loop over the SqlDataReader.
In your query you retrieve only the column `name` but in the loop you try to read two columns (GetString), at index 0 (it is the name column) and at index 1 but you don't have a second column in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the input, It extracts the client's name now, but I have another issue : a new error is thrown immediately after msgbox gets closed
Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Yes, it is the myReader. You have enclosed the creation of the MySqlDataReader in a using block. This means than when you exit from the block the myReader has been closed and disposed. You don't need the line myReader.Close. By the way, you should use the same concept (Using Block) also for the SqlConnection and the SqlCommand